Symfony enviroment variables in .env file doesn't work in prod
I'm running a Symfony application within a Docker container. In the development environment, I can see all environment variables using the debug:container --env-vars command. However, when I switch to the production environment (also configured in the .env file and it works), running the same command returns "No environment variables are being used."
I've ensured that the .env file and the .env.local.php file are correctly set up, and I can see their contents with the debug:dotenv command. Additionally, I ran composer dump-env prod, but the issue persists.
What I’ve Tried:

Generated environment variables for production:
composer dump-env prod

Cleared Symfony cache for production:
php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod

Verified contents of .env.local.php:
The file contains all expected environment variables.

Checked environment variables via Symfony command:
php bin/console debug:container --env-vars
This command works in development but shows "No environment variables are being used" in production.


Additional Context:
Symfony Version: 7.0.8
PHP Version: 8.2.20
Edit: I have checked and realized that env. variables are used in the application successfully. is debug:container --env-vars not suposed to show them in prod? If so, how can i debug them?

use bin/console debug:dotenv instead.
This will show you which .env files are in use and where each variable is coming from. In your case, since you are running composer dump-env prod, they will all be pulled from the dumped php file (which is why, I suspect, you are getting the notice you are).

I have already mentioned in my question: "I've ensured that the .env file and the .env.local.php file are correctly set up, and I can see their contents with the debug:dotenv command."

I can see everything in debug:dotenvbut i want to debug what env variables are used in container in prod.
